# \input - \return-command

Tags: input

I'm looking for a command like `\return` with which I can manually exit a TeX file, which is included by `\input`.

(At the end of my TeX file are some notices, which I sometimes want to print, sometimes not.)

Comment: Use `\endinput`

Comment: So easy! Thank you, that was, what I was looking for. Please write it as an answer :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `\endinput`. Everything after it will be ignored.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend you use either an environment, or an `\ifdefined` to select if the notices are displayed or not:

[image]

With the "environment" version you can use `\DisableMyNotices` and `\EnableMyNotices` to toggle if you want to see the notices or not.

---

### Code: `\ifdefined`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{MyInput.tex}
This is text I want always included.

\ifdefined\IncludeNotices
    \fcolorbox{red}{yellow!40}{%
    These are notices that I only want sometimes.%
    }%
\fi
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
Using normal input I get just the text\par

\begin{mdframed}
    \input{MyInput}
\end{mdframed}

\bigskip 

But with \verb|\IncludeNotices| defined:\par
\def\IncludeNotices{}
\begin{mdframed}
    \input{MyInput}
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

---

### Code: environment version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{MyNotices}{}%
\newcommand{\EnableMyNotices}{\RenewEnviron{MyNotices}{\BODY}}
\newcommand{\DisableMyNotices}{\RenewEnviron{MyNotices}{}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{MyInput.tex}
This is text I want always included.

\begin{MyNotices}
    \fcolorbox{red}{yellow!40}{%
    These are notices that I only want sometimes.%
    }%
\end{MyNotices}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\DisableMyNotices
With \verb|\DisableMyNotices| defined:\par

\begin{mdframed}
    \input{MyInput}
\end{mdframed}

\bigskip 

\EnableMyNotices
But with \verb|\EnableMyNotices| defined:\par
\begin{mdframed}
    \input{MyInput}
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 Nice way to style up notices, but I just needed a simple out-of-here-command :)